# Website traffic - with no money (backlinks, spam, likes, tweets)

Tags: backlinks, traffic, advertising, website-promotion

I read a lot of things around the web.

I saw people selling 4K backlinks and social real users tweets, likes, sharing links on Facebook, Twitter, Instagram etc..

Now,

- assuming you have opened a site which is on beta stage and users needs invitations to signup
- assuming you are not an administrator of any huge Facebook or social community (Facebook groups, meetup groups, forums, chats etc..),
- assuming you don't have much money to spend for a huge campaign on paying ads,
- assuming you want to stay out from venture capitalists, angels and so on (at least to check if you can do it without external/third parties help)

so...

Is "trusted" SPAM, or paying backlinks, the only way you can go for getting some traffic to your website?

If not can you describe how can you promote your website on the web excluding all the points above?

Comment: Sorry, but I had to remove your bounty and close this question. Asking how others would launch a beta website is subjective and not suitable for this website.

Comment: @JohnConde totally disagree but i have to stay at modertors no problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best source of free traffic is search engines.  [People perform around two trillion searches on Google each year](http://www.statisticbrain.com/google-searches/).  Of the people that click on a result, [94% click on the organic listings and only 6% click on the ads](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2200730/Organic-vs.-Paid-Search-Results-Organic-Wins-94-of-Time).   That means that there are more free clicks available than there are all of the paid clicks that you named combined.

Search engine optimization (SEO) is a huge topic beyond the scope of this post.  The biggest requirement is that you need to build a website that people like when they click from the search engines.  Your site must serve their need better that the other sites that are in the results.

---

The second large source of free traffic is from something that goes "viral".  That is, the content is so compelling that users share it with their friends.

- ["Gangnam Style" by PSY got nearly 3 billion views on YouTube](http://www.technewsdaily.com/15994-10-biggest-viral-videos.html)
- [The "Farmville" games on Facebook went viral and got 83 million monthly players at their peak](http://www.dubitlimited.com/blog/2012/11/06/farmville2-viral-mechanics/)
- [What is viral marketing](http://www.dfj.com/news/article_25.shtml) gives several more examples such as Hotmail and ICQ.

---

The third way to attract eyeballs for free is through [public relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_relations) (PR).   Have news organizations run stories about you, your organization, or your product instead of paying them for advertisng.   The effectiveness of PR is usually measured against the amount of money it would have taken to get similar size or length advertisements.

Comment: nice  answer! thanks, what i'm wondering is how can you get organic traffic without having to spam backlinks allround?

Comment: what i mean is how can people click your site from Search results when site still not being in search results cause you have no traffic on it? it's like a dog chasing its tail?

Comment: I would recommend that you never spam or purchase backlinks.  When Google catches you doing that you lose all your rankings.  You can always rank for something as long as it isn't too competitive just by creating content for it.  See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52839/should-i-start-with-less-competitive-keywords-as-a-strategy

Comment: and how can google verify that backlinks were bought? just to understand, i will not do that and just trying catching best practices to start from 0

Comment: That is too big a question to answer in a comment.  Ask it as another question and I'll be happy to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your website is solving a problem ... a real problem faced by a community.

1. Find this community, meet them in real life. Being a member of such a community goes a long way.
2. Identify the influencers in this community.
3. Talk to them and get their buy-in on how your site is awesome
4. Start small and simply focus on influencers and the "geeks" in that community

I do not think that traffic should be a metric that you need to measure. In case if you are already monetizing on the site, then it should be revenues/purchases. Setup Google Analytics with goals and then start measuring which traffic generating tactic gets you the dough.

Comment: With traffic i mean , get people to the site so people can understand at least that the site exists

Comment: Also what if i'm in Asia and i'm building a wbsite for Americans? i can't meet they in real life

Comment: Definitly, how long it will takes, for example, to get 1000 users to look at your site with your methods? (without spamming links)

Comment: Why don't you learn SEO by yourself? And generate traffic. It wont take much time.

Comment: 1000 users who are not interested gets you no sales and a big bill.  You don't have to meet face to face, you just need to pick your best target audience and reach out to them.

Comment: @JamesRyan So d'you mean entering an online community (by your target), and start to send private messages or forum posts and all this without having to spam? Probably in 2020 year you get 500 users to your site and 500 accounts banned from the community i guess, please  explain better :)

Comment: no, that is the opposite of what I said.  Find people who WANT your product and will recommend it.  Spam gets deleted, it doesn't increase sales.